# WhatsApp - Set message sound that's different from contact ringtone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

On my Android phone, I've set my wife to have a specific ringtone (through the built-in Contacts app). Now every time she sends me a WhatsApp message, I get alerted with this ringtone.

I'd like to keep my wife's ringtone for incoming calls but have a different (shorter) tone sound when she sends me a WhatsApp message. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not shorten the sound using a sound editor and then use the file where ever you want? When choosing a tone from Settings, choose [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) and select the sound file you want to hear for notifications.

Comment: Thanks, but if I shorten the file then I get a short ringtone for calls. I want a regular ringtone for calls and a short notification sound for WhatsApp notifications.